# Azure sql db Active directoy password authentication not working in iis

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I have Azure sql db connected with active directory password authentication.

The connection is establishing properly from visual studio, but when I hosted in IIS I get this error:

> Unable to load adalsql.dll (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Error code: 0x2.

The same issue is happening  for Active directory integrated authentication also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it at the application level as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory). IIS does not support Azure SQL Authentication.